# Use ContextCompat.getColor() correctly to style based on theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

In Android M, I saw that getColor(int id) was replaced with ContextCompat.getColor(Context context, int id).

I'm new to styling with themes in Android, so I wasn't sure how to use this function correctly. Currently, the way I'm organizing my colors is by defining attrs like so:

**values/attr.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="button_bg" format="reference|color"/>
</resources>
```

then I reference them like so:

**values/themes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyTheme.White">
        <item name="button_bg">#fff</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyTheme.Black">
        <item name="button_bg">#000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

this works.
However, how do I now get `button_bg` in java?
I tried `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.attr.button_bg)` but that gave me an error of `Resource not found`.

Am I approaching this incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Have seen, the Question was longer than a year ago, so hope i can still help other people with this.

You can simply use the attribute id in your XML:

```
<View
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   android:layout_width="50dp"
   android:background="?attr/button_bg">
  ..../>
```

In your Activity you could set your theme in on Create:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.your_theme);//your theme
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    ....
}
```

The rest is made automatically by android.

To access the color depending on the theme via code you can use the following function:

```
@ColorInt
public int getColorByAttributeId(Context context, @AttrRes int attrIdForColor){
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    Resources.Theme theme = context.getTheme();
    theme.resolveAttribute(attrIdForColor, typedValue, true);
    return typedValue.data;
}
```

The method is simply "stupid", which means there no check that the requested attribute color is a real color resource.